# Can anyone find out how to submit a form that has <c:forEach> tag with all input values?

Tags: html, spring, jsp

I have a form named 'myForm' that has  tag.
number of ${list} may change.
Is there any way that I can submit all the value of subject?
I will use for loop in Java to update the data into database.

Please somebody help me out...

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="forMyForm">                                         
<c:choose>  
<c:when test="${fn:length(list) > 0}">
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="privateId" value="${row.PRIVATE_ID}"/>
        <input type="text" name="subject" value="${row.SUBJECT}"/>  
    </c:forEach>
</c:when>
</c:choose>
</form>
```

Comment: Add a submit button to the form, and press it. That will submit the form. Also note that the c:choose and the c:when are unnecessary: if the list is empty, iterating on it won't produce anything.

Comment: Sorry, I think what I explained had you misunderstand what I want. There are multiple values expressed by <c:forEach>.  I want to submit multiple values of 'privateId' and 'subject'.

Comment: 'privateId[fn]',  'subject[fn], like this.   so I can recall the value of inputs by 'privateId[0], 'privateId[1] '

Comment: You don't need to change anything to your form. Just submit it as is, and use `httpServletRequest.getParameterValues("subject")` to get all the values of the subject inputs.

Comment: ohhhhhh, I got it! I used    String [] privateId = request.getParameterValues("subject");   and I could print it by 'subject[0~i]' Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was perfectly answered by JB Nizet at Comments.

I used `httpServletRequest.getParameterValues("nameOfVariable")`
and it returned the array of the values in String.